# Управление панелью навигации

Tags: java, android, root, navigationbar

Скрыл программно статус-бар и нижнюю панель навигации. Но при свайпе снизу вверх в нижней части экрана навигационная панель выезжает. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы она не выезжала или заблокировать нажатие кнопок "назад", "домой" и "запущенные приложения"? Или это только с root-правами?

Answer (score 0):

Скрывает значки на панели, вернее превращает их в маленькие точки, панель не скрывает

```
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE );
```

Убирается или нет status bar зависит от значения параметра  tv.hideStatusBar.enable в файле build.prop. Если его значение равняется true, то панель убирается просто установкой темы с Fullsceen или другими стандартными способами, если же значение false, то не убирается, а максимум сворачивается в точки. Поменять значение tv.hideStatusBar.enable без root доступа не представляется мне возможным.

Можно убрать закрыть панель иначе, но требует root:

Убрать:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
```

Вернуть как было:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"am","startservice","-n","com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"});
```